# Force Windows 7 to think it is running on Adapter Power and not battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

Anyone know how to make a Windows 7 Laptop think it is running on AC Adapter power?

This laptop (HP G62 series) has a usable battery which holds charge but it has a not-official power adapter which I think is causing a problem.

If I remove the battery and run the laptop via the cable, it doesn't switch on.  If I put the battery back in it switches on and uses battery power only.  If I plug the cable in it begins to charge but the icon doesn't indicate charging.

I am trying to restore factory settings, or install windows updates, flash bios but unfortunately I cannot as the O.S always detects it is running on battery power - regardless of the cable being plugged in.

I have read and tried a few things, all don't work!  I am "hoping" someone may know a way to force Windows into thinking it is always running on the power cable (not the battery).

Comment: "If I remove the battery and run the laptop via the cable, it doesn't switch on. If I put the battery back in it switches on and uses battery power only."  If it doesn't run on AC without a battery, then the battery isn't your problem.  Ensure the adapter is working properly, and putting out the expected power.

Comment: I know it's the adapter but I had assumed it is because it is not a HP product.  I can't check the output here, I assume I need an voltmeter. I was hoping I could either use a product specific driver or more likely hack windows to make it think it is running off power...registry setting?!

Comment: Ahh, I thought it was a 3rd party battery.  If you're not using the right power adapter (one that puts out the right voltage and supplies the right amperage required by the laptop) , then that's why you're having these problems.  Have you confirmed the replacement has the right specs for the notebook? Getting the right adapter is probably MUCH easier than trying to hack Windows to ignore a lot of its power-saving features.

Comment: See: [Why won't my battery charge when plugged into a knockoff AC adapter?](http://superuser.com/questions/35948/why-wont-my-battery-charge-when-plugged-into-a-knockoff-ac-adapter?rq=1)

Comment: All I can tell is what it is supposed to, I can't test it's actual performance here :(  I just don't have the tools.  It's from some company called "hootoo" but as I understand it they actually supply components to hp.  I guess I either need to buy a new adapter or just manually wipe the pc rather than using the recovery tools

Comment: *> I have read and tried a few things* - Could you specify them? I don't whether it would be an actual solution for you but (if you haven't already) try opening the Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`) and disable **Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery**.

Comment: That did the trick, I had attempted to uninstall it but simply disabling it worked...at least it did for one of the setup packages I am using (It didn't for the windows-hp-built in "recovery manager".

Comment: No surprise after installing Linux it works fine, no issues with power adapter or battery.

Comment: Disabling the "ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery" worked for my issue.