# Dell Inspiron 6400 AC-Adaptor Less finicky BIOS version?

Tags: bios, power-supply, dell-inspiron

I am the recipient of a Dell Inspiron 6400 which I received with a dead battery although the ac adaptor would power the unit. I obtained a new battery for it and installed it thinking my problems would be over, but sadly I'm getting the AC-Adaptor = Unknown Device Installed with BIOS version A14. I've reviewed [this.](https://superuser.com/questions/104023/dell-inspiron-6400-indicates-the-wrong-power-adapter-is-plugged-in-and-will-not) But my question is does anyone know of a version of the BIOS that will ignore the blocking circuit and **allow the battery to charge**? I don't really want to throw more money at this old laptop buying an AC adaptor when the problem may be at board level. but I hate to pitch it because otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Are you using a dell power adapter or some other brand?

Comment: It's a MayDay Tech 65W-DL04 providing 19.5V @ 3.34 amps

Comment: [Why won't my battery charge when plugged into a knockoff AC adapter?](https://superuser.com/a/35973)

Comment: @DavidPostill I understand that the blocking circuit is there. What I'm wondering is if there is a BIOS version that fails to check it or fakes the signal. I'm willing to roll back to a previous BIOS if it will allow the battery to charge (granted not best practices but this system isn't critical and isn't worth much)